# Outlook 2010 Attachment Checker Macro - Only what i write

Tags: vba, outlook, attachment

I have been using the below code in outlook 2010 to remind me to add an attachment if I reference one in the email and forget to attach anything. However, I was wondering if there was a way to only check the text I write (and not checking the quoted text when I reply to an email). Due to my company's security settings I am unable to add an add-in, and so need to rely on VBA.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
‘ Pops up a reminder if the word “attach” is found but there is no attachment on your email.
Dim m As Variant
Dim strBody As String
Dim intIn As Long
Dim intAttachCount As Integer, intStandardAttachCount As Integer

On Error GoTo handleError

‘Edit the following line if you have a signature on your email that includes images or other files. Make intStandardAttachCount equal the number of files in your signature.
intStandardAttachCount = 0

strBody = LCase(Item.Body)

intIn = InStr(1, strBody, “original message”)

If intIn = 0 Then intIn = Len(strBody)

intIn = InStr(1, Left(strBody, intIn), “attachment”)

intAttachCount = Item.Attachments.Count

If intIn > 0 And intAttachCount <= intStandardAttachCount Then

m = MsgBox(“It appears that you mean to send an attachment,” & vbCrLf & “but there is no attachment to this message.” & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & “Do you still want to send?”, vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbMsgBoxSetForeground)

If m = vbNo Then Cancel = True

End If

handleError:

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
MsgBox “Outlook Attachment Reminder Error: ” & Err.Description, vbExclamation, “Outlook Attachment Reminder Error”
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This did what you want some time ago.

```
intIn = InStr(1, strBody, “original message”)

If intIn = 0 Then intIn = Len(strBody)

intIn = InStr(1, Left(strBody, intIn), “attachment”)
```

The text “original message” is no longer used to separate new from old.

The new separator is "From: "

```
intIn = InStr(1, strBody, “From: ”)
```

Comment: This should work most of the time, unless for some reason OP has included the string "from: " somewhere in the text (which is probably unlikely, but definitely not impossible). Along similar line of reasoning, OP could configure Outlook to always add a signature, and could then do `intIn = Instr(1, strBody, "YOUR NAME HERE")`.  This is neither a guarantee, although it seems *less likely* that OP would include his/her own full name in the body of the email. /rambling  :).